# how i display this type of picker image?

Tags: android

[image]
I want to create this type of picker how i do this?
[image]

Comment: Search on `Google` before asking such type of questions....

Comment: plz tell me which control i used for this picker because i have no idea

Comment: It's just and `Picker Dailog` load it as `Dialog Activity`. Simple....

Comment: i searched on google but it gives only number picker dialog hoe i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [this](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel)  type of spinner wheel library.